# how to open webpage in c# without using webbrowser class

Tags: c#

I want to know how to open webpage in c# without using webbrowser class. First time on c sharp. I tried below but that did not work. Can anyone help.

```
   HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://google.com");
        myRequest.Method = "GET";
        WebResponse myResponse = myRequest.GetResponse();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
        string result = sr.ReadToEnd();
        sr.Close();
        myResponse.Close();
```

Comment: `but that did not work.` is not helpful. What's the problem you're having? Is any exception being thrown, is the content empty?

Comment: What do you mean by "open webpage"? Get content of page and store it to string variable?

Comment: Do you want a screen scrapper? https://nugetmusthaves.com/Tag/scraping

Comment: I want a new window to open up

Comment: What is the problem of using webbrowser?

Answer (score 1):

If you try to simply open a website without doing something else with it, you could do something like that to open the defined default browser:

```
string url = "http://google.com";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url);
```